# Tidymodels Predict Error in R while predict on test

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am using below code to build and predict model using `tidymodels`. I am fairly new to tidymodels, so may be I am totally wrong in my approach. But here is what the problem is.

When input datatype for test dataset is different from train, I am getting this error. Otherwise, the code works fine(In cases where train and test data structures are identical). I am assuming that the preprocessing step should have tackled this while processing test data.

If anyone knows/encountered this problem. Please let me know the possible solution.

I search for this issue, but haven't found anything of this sort.

Thanks for looking into it.

**Code**:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(dplyr)

mt1 <- mtcars ## assume this is the train data
mt2 <- mtcars ## assume this is the test data
mt2$mpg <- as.character(mt2$mpg) ## just forcing them to be character to reproduce the problem in my actual data
mt2$qsec <- as.character(mt2$qsec) 

dp_pipe <- recipe(am ~ .,data=mt1) %>% 
  update_role(cyl,vs,new_role = "drop_vars") %>% 
  update_role(mpg,
              disp,
              drat,wt, qsec, new_role="to_numeric") %>% 
  step_rm(has_role("drop_vars")) %>% 
  step_mutate_at(has_role(match = "to_numeric"),fn = as.numeric)


# Cross folds
folds = vfold_cv(mt1, v = 10)

# define parameter grid to be tuned
my_grid = tibble(penalty = 10^seq(-2, -1, length.out = 10))

# define lasso model
lasso_mod = linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                       penalty = tune(),
                       mixture = 1) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet")

# add everything to a workflow
wf = workflow() %>%
  add_model(lasso_mod) %>%
  add_recipe(dp_pipe)

# tune the workflow
my_res <- wf %>% 
  tune_grid(resamples = folds,
            grid = my_grid,
            control = control_grid(verbose = FALSE, save_pred = TRUE),
            metrics = metric_set(rmse))

best_mod = my_res %>% select_best("rmse")
best_mod

final_fitted = finalize_workflow(wf, best_mod) %>% fit(data=mt1)

# predicted for train  
final_fitted %>%  
  predict(mt1)

final_fitted %>% 
  predict(mt2)
```

**Error at my end:**

```
> Error: ! Can't convert `data$mpg` <character> to match type of `mpg`
> <double>. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Why are you changing the data type of the test data? Train should be some of the observations (rows) to build the model, and Test should be the remaining observations to test the model, but the columns/datatypes need to be the same.

Comment: @Carl, I  am just changing it to show that , In my case the source system is different for train and test dataset.  Since these source system are from different places, we are seeing different data types. At first we wrote code to fix it, but now we are thinking to imbed them in tidymodels. I am just interested to know here, how to deal with such scenarios using tidymodels. I hope this clarifies the question more. Also the test data is not just test data, it is out of time data (means data from a different time frame)

Comment: I think you'd need to standardise them first such that they could, in effect, have come from the same data frame.

Comment: This is expected behavior and is not likely to be changed. When you create a recipe you are specifying what variables that are used. Additionally workflows checks that the column types are the same when applied to new data.
Naming and setting types should be done before recipes, preferable when reading in the data to R.